# cURL can not get the right output

Tags: curl

Try to download this page: http://www.4shared.com/get/B4AgMkcw/cookies.html
I can use wget/firefox to get the whole page, but curl just prints nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you didn't bother to post what you actually tried, in terms of the curl command you used... I'm almost certain you forgot to use the `-L` flag to tell curl to follow the redirects..

`curl -L -o cookies.html http://www.4shared.com/get/B4AgMkcw/cookies.html`

Comment: The most interesting thing is that the blue download button on that page has a hyper reference to the page itself, but my firefox browser opens a different page. What's up?

Comment: Its not the same link. It makes you wait and then it gives you a link that contains a key in the url to download the file. No idea what you mean.